# NonClustered Index in SQl server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am just doing a performance test on my application database tables . I am not bad in the concept of indexing in sql server .perhaps when i came practical my theories are damn confusing me . hi hi

here my question is  , Could you please tell me a scenario in which i need to use multiple non-clustered index on a single table ? .

Do we need more than one index for a single book ? I am confused .

Please help.

Comment: When you might be looking up values in multiple different ways. e.g. search a table of people by date of birth or name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indixing is very complex and beyond the scope of a simple reply here.  However, in general, you add indexes onto tables based on how you will read data from the table.

if you have a table:

```
YourTable
ID          int identity  PK
WidgetName  varchar(10)
WidgetSize  numeric(6,2)
```

...and you frequently run: `SELECT.. WHERE WidgetName='xyz'` then add an index on `WidgetName`
if you never `SELECT.. WHERE WidgetSize =12.4` then do not add an index for that column.

Comment: Thanks , then what does INCLUDE clause used for ? and how it works ?

Comment: when your query uses an index it searches throu the index data, once it finds your row, it uses a "pointer" back to the actual row in the table to get all columns needed for the query. If your index contains all columns necessary for the query, then it can skip the step of looking up the actual row (it has all the info necessary in the index).  Most of the time you only want an index on certain columns (especially if it is unique). the `INCLUDE` allows you to add additional columns of data into the index for data purposes only & they are not part of the searchable or unique part of index...

Comment: ...They would only help avoid the need to go back to the actual table and get those columns.  This is one of the reasons why `SELECT *` is bad, even if the query uses an index, you need to go back to table and grab all the columns.  There is a slight penalty to using an `INCLUDE` on the index, every `insert` or `update` must push more data to the index.  In a typical application where you read many times, this is usually very minor compared the the gain from the select speed.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong , Non Clustered Indexing is not creating another sorted copy of the table , but it has only the pointer dictionary to the actual data leaf (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx). In  your above statement confused me as , if i include additional columns , i don't need to compare the actual data . i think this concept is wrong .. Actually what a index structure

Comment: I think this link is proving your statement.. (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking185.htm) index is also keeping the data along with intermediate as well as leaf pages .

Comment: `Correct me if i am wrong , Non Clustered Indexing is not creating another sorted copy of the table , but it has only the pointer dictionary` I never say that the index is a `sorted copy of the table` only that it contains the indexed columns and the pointer to the real table, and the `INCLUDE` columns if any.